# Importing data from a PDF form to a database

Tags: mysql, database, forms, pdf, xfdf

I have to do a project at work at the moment where data from received PDFs are supposed to be saved in a DB.
The process shoould look as follows:

1. Customer fills out PDF form
2. Form is sent as an attachment in XFDF-format via e-mail to our company
3. The received data gets imported into a MySQL database

This process is supposed to happen automatically.

By now my first approach was to save the attachment automatically in a dedicated folder with the help of VBA. Afterwards I would handle the newly created file and import the data into the DB (but I don't know how at the moment).

My question is if this is the right way and if so how can I programatically import the XFDF data into the MySQL DB? If this approach is too complicated or not possible in what ways should I alter the process?

Thank you in advance!